# How to create JSESSIONID for API test

Tags: java, node.js, angular, jsp, jsessionid

We have a JSP application which we are migrating to Angular and Rest APIs. Rest APIs checks if JSESSIONID has been supplied in the cookie and is valid.

JSESSIONID is created on login (which is currently JSP) and later on Angular pages use this cookie for API calls(which works).

I am writing Node.js test (javascript) to invoke APIs directly for component test. The Apis require JSESSIONID to authenticate the call. How can I create JSESSIONID for Node.js tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you haven't implemented additional authorisation approach for the API layer e.g. [OAuth 2.0](https://oauth.net/2/) then simply invoke whatever is the login page for your application and save the `JSESSIONID` obtained from the login page response.

Sane security guidelines dictate that `JSESSIONID` should be regenerated on login and discarded on logout to prevent session attacks e.g. session hijacking. You should go through login process at least once per test suite unless you are disabling authorisation in your API during tests.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply @Karol. I am new to Java so can I confirm that you are suggesting to create a new API in Java which will do the similar thing as currently Login JSP page does? (i.e. create new session request.getSession().setAttribute("loggedIn",true)) and return the session Id back as API response?